# ¿Como puedo usar sort con un vector de punteros?

Tags: c++, punteros, array

Estoy intentando usar sort con un vector tipo `vector<node*>` donde `node` es una variable que yo mismo me he creado. Sin embargo no estoy teniendo éxito, no me deja meter esa función dentro del método sort. Este es mi código:

```
int compOrganizar(node* nodo1, node* nodo2){

    return (nodo1->getF() < nodo2->getF());
}

void expandir_nodo(node nodo){

    if (isGoal(nodo)){

        haveSol = true;
    }

    else{
        generateIzquierda(nodo);
        generateDerecha(nodo);

        sort(abiertos.begin(),abiertos.end(),compOrganizar);
    }
```

¿Alguien sabría decirme que tengo mal? Muchas gracias de antemano a todos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar la utilidad [`std::sort`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) de [`<algorithm>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
std::vector<node *> nodos;

// rellenar vector...

// ordenar el vector...
std::sort(nodos.begin(), nodos.end());
```

Pero como el tipo almacenado en el `std::vector` es un puntero te ordenará por el valor del puntero, lo cuál no tiene ningún sentido.

Por suerte, `std::sort` acepta un parámetro adicional que consiste en una función para ordenar tu tipo, suponiendo que quieras ordenar los nodos por `node::getF` podrías hacer:

```
std::vector<node *> nodos;

// rellenar vector...

// ordenar el vector...
std::sort(nodos.begin(), nodos.end(), [](const node *&a, const node *&b)
{
    return a->getF() < b->getF();
});
```

El tercer parámetro que le estoy pasando a `std::sort` es una [expresión lambda](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 5):

No te está funcionando porque la función que espera `sort` debe retornar un booleano:

```
   bool compOrganizar(node* nodo1, node* nodo2){
// ^^^^ 

    return (nodo1->getF() < nodo2->getF());
}
```

No hay que perder de vista que C++ se basa en un tipado fuerte... es más quisquilloso que el compilador de C

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero conseguí solucionarlo con la respuesta de PaperBirdMaster.

Comment: @AlfonsoRodríguez ambas respuestas solucionan tu problema.  La mia te explica el motivo por el cual te falla el código (y como arreglarlo) y la de paperbirdmaster te explica otra forma de hacerlo. Con esto te intento decir que no es necesario que expliques por qué das una respuesta como válida... así es como funciona SO... son las reglas del juego y no estamos aquí para competir por los ticks verdes

Comment: No era por insinuar que había ganado nadie. Tan solo quería agradecerte el esfuerzo que te ha tomado tu respuesta y la ayuda. ¡Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @AlfonsoRodríguez no estaba insinuando eso. Como he visto que eras relativamente nuevo en SO te informaba sobre el tema. Disculpa si no me he sabido explicar correctamente